# How do I combine sympy derivatives with numpy array expressions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sympy

I hope I can make my question clear.

I'm using `scipy.optimize.minimize` to find the maximum likelihood estimators for some experimental data. The data is 2d (NxN) so in my notes, the log-likelihood function (the function I need to maximize) looks like this:

[image: formula]

So [image: formula] is a 2d array that depends on my particular model while n<sub>ij</sub> is the measured 2d data. In the code, I wrote the same function in this way:

```
def logll(params, *args):

    A, x0, y0, bkg = params
    pico, F = args

    x, y = np.arange(pico.shape[0]), np.arange(pico.shape[1])

    erfi = erf((x + 1 - x0) / F) - erf((x - x0) / F)
    erfj = erf((y + 1 - y0) / F) - erf((y - y0) / F)

    lambda_p = A * F**2 * np.pi * erfi[:, np.newaxis] * erfj / 4 + bkg

    return - np.sum(pico * np.log(lambda_p) - lambda_p)
```

The important thing to note here is that my data is part of a 2d array and for that reason the product `erfi * erfj` and `bkg` are `NxN` arrays. The only way I knew to code this was as above, that is, writing `erfi` and `erfj` as 1d arrays and multiplying them as `erfi[:, np.newaxis] * erfj` to get the right-shape array.

This whole thing was working just fine and I could find my estimators by just calling

```
minimize(logll, x0=[A, x0, y0, bkg], args=(peak, F), method='Powell')
```

Anyway, this Powell method wasn't fast enough so I wanted to use one like `Newton-CG` which is supposed to be faster. The downside is that it needs the jacobian and hessian and for that I have to differentiate `logll` with respect to my 4 parameters. I didn't want to do it by hand so I gave it a try with `sympy`. I had to take out the `[:, np.newaxis]` part from my expressions but other that that the derivatives went just fine.

The jacobian `ll_jac` is the 1d array containing the derivative of `logll` with respect to the four fitting parameters. I obtained it defining `A`, `x0`, `y0`, `bkg`, `x` and `y` as symbols with `sympy` and then differentiating this way:

```
logll.diff(A)
logll.diff(x0)
logll.diff(y0)
logll.diff(bkg)
```

The hessian `ll_hess` is the 2d array containing the second derivative of logll with respect to the four parameters and I got it by doing

```
logll.diff(A, A)
logll.diff(A, x0)
```

and so on. It was here, before doing any differentiation, that I had to take off the `[:, np.newaxis]` part from the `logll` expresion in order for `sympy` to work.

So, finally, with all the jacobian and hessian at hand, I tried

```
minimize(logll, x0=[A, x0, y0, bkg], args=(peak, F), 
         method='Newton-CG', jac=ll_jac, hess=ll_hess)
```

And I got the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 351, in minimize
**options)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1365, in _minimize_newtoncg
update = alphak * pk

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

which I suspect has something to do with the fact that `erfi` and `erfj` are 1d-arrays and `bkg` is a 2d-array.

So my question would be the following: how do I need to write down the expressions so that `numpy` and `sympy` don't get into conflict? Is there a better way of writing the product `erfi * erfj` and still get the 2d array I want?

Comment: What are `ll_jac` and `ll_hess` and how do you obtain them from sympy?

Comment: I've just added the info in the question

Comment: Take a look at `lambdify`.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (i.e. a self-contained program that potential answerers can copy/paste or download and run to reproduce the error, assuming we have numpy and sympy installed)

Comment: By the way, check out [`numpy.outer()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) for doing the product, though I have no idea if that's related to the problem you're actually having.