# How to Implement Brachistochrone with Manim SciPy/SymPy/Numpy and Python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, manim

I am just learning about `manim` from the tutorial, I modify to add another line, just a `-x+50`, then I was wondering whether the ball that are moving is actually correct, can we determine the speed for each curve?

this is my code :

```
# python3 -m manim manim-argminexample.py ArgMinExample -p -ql
from manim import *

class ArgMinExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ax = Axes(
            x_range=[0, 10], y_range=[0, 100, 10], axis_config={"include_tip": False}
        )
        labels = ax.get_axis_labels(x_label="x", y_label="f(x)")

        t = ValueTracker(0)

        def func(x):
            return 2 * (x - 5) ** 2
        graph = ax.plot(func, color=MAROON)

        def func2(x):
            return -x+50
        graph2 = ax.plot(func2, color=GREEN)


        initial_point = [ax.coords_to_point(t.get_value(), func(t.get_value()))]
        dot = Dot(point=initial_point)
        dot2 = Dot(point=initial_point)

        dot.add_updater(lambda x: x.move_to(ax.c2p(t.get_value(), func(t.get_value()))))
        dot2.add_updater(lambda x: x.move_to(ax.c2p(t.get_value(), func2(t.get_value()))))
        x_space = np.linspace(*ax.x_range[:2],200)
        minimum_index = func(x_space).argmin()

        self.add(ax, labels, graph, dot)
        self.add(ax, labels, graph2, dot2)
        self.play(t.animate.set_value(x_space[minimum_index]))
        self.wait()
```

How am I suppose to create animation for Brachistochrone with manim like this:

[image: 1]

I believe using NumPy or SymPy can help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810818](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810818/how-do-i-combine-sympy-derivatives-with-numpy-array-expressions) maybe you mean this

Comment: @DiegoReim I find another website that able to do computation but not the animation. I will try to working on the animation. Thanks.